# Getting firebase to send push notifications to andriod

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am setting up push notifications in firebase. I am trying to send a test text message directly from firebase but it is not making it to my phone.

[image]

I have the token ID from my phone. Should I be testing on my physical device or an emulator?

Or is there something I need to do on my android phone to receive messages? I already receive messages from other apps.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/fcm